# Inconsistent login state

Tags: login, logout

I'm logged in with "Remember me" checked. I then click the logout link. At this point I appear to be logged out - I can no longer access member-only pages, and menus that only appear for logged in users are no longer visible. But if I go to the login page, it shows me as logged in - I can't enter my credentials at this point. I've tried deleting cookies, but that has no effect.

How do I get out of this state?

(I'm running WP Membership, in case that makes a difference.)

Comment: it sounds like you have a page caching system or caching plugin/service that isn't configured to not cache pages from logged in users and `wp-admin`, but if this is specific to WP Membership then you'll need to ask their support

Comment: You're right - it's almost certainly a caching issue. The host servers appear to have some level of caching implemented by default. Now I just have to dig into the configuration settings to see how to defeat this.